# c++ inheritance problem "undefined reference to"

Tags: c++, inheritance

While practicing inheritance in c++, I kept on getting the following error:

base1.o: In function `Base1::Base1()':
base1.cpp:(.text+0x75): undefined reference to`Base2::Base2()'
base1.o: In function `Base1::Base1()':
base1.cpp:(.text+0xa5): undefined reference to`Base2::Base2()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [test] Error 1

I removed all unnecessary code, so that only this is left:

*base1.h* :

```
#include "base2.h"
#ifndef BASE1_H_
#define BASE1_H_

class Base1 : public Base2 {  

public:
Base1();   
};

#endif
```

*base1.cpp* :

```
#include <QStringList>
#include <QTextStream>
#include "base1.h"
#include "base2.h"

QTextStream cout(stdout);
QTextStream cin(stdin);

Base1::Base1() : Base2() {
cout << "\nB1\n\n" << flush;
}
```

*base2.h* :

```
#ifndef BASE2_H_
#define BASE2_H_

class Base2 {

public:
Base2();
};

#endif
```

*base2.cpp* :

```
#include <QStringList>
#include <QTextStream>
#include "base2.h"

QTextStream cout(stdout);
QTextStream cin(stdin);


Base1::Base1() {
cout << "\nB2\n\n" << flush;   
}
```

*child.cpp* :

```
#include <QStringList>
#include <QTextStream>
#include "base1.h"
#include "base2.h"

QTextStream cout(stdout);
QTextStream cin(stdin);


Base1::Base1() {
cout << "\nB2\n\n" << flush;
}
```

This is probably an easy problem, but I have been spending like 2 hours looking for a solution on google and didn't find anything, so I would appreciate any help.

---

Hi,

thanks everyone for your answers so far.

I have changed 
*base2.cpp* to:

```
#include <QStringList>
#include <QTextStream>
#include "base2.h"

QTextStream cout(stdout);
QTextStream cin(stdin);


Base2::Base2() {
cout << "\nB2\n\n" << flush;
}
```

however, I still get the same error. I think it must have something to do with the "#include", but I don't know how to do it right :(.

Answer (score 2):

Very simple: you declare `Base2()` but never define it. You must, even if it's empty... or don't declare it at all and an empty one will be generated for you.

Perhaps `Base1::Base1()` in base2.cpp should read `Base2::Base2()`?

[child.cpp shouldn't have definitions for any of them.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule)

**Edit** You've said you're still having problems.

I'm going to assume that you paid attention to the above and removed the extraneous definition of `Base1::Base1()` from child.cpp.

How are you building your project? It should be like:

```
 g++ base1.cpp base2.cpp child.cpp -o myProgram
```

or like:

```
 g++ base1.cpp -o base1.o
 g++ base2.cpp -o base2.o
 g++ child.cpp -o child.o
 g++ base1.o base2.o child.o -o myProgram
```

(which is often the result of working with a makefile or other automated build processes).

Comment: thanks, so I changed 
base2.cpp to 
Base2::Base2() {
cout << "\nB2\n\n" << flush;   
}
but I keep getting the same error :(,

Comment: @Anselm: The error _must_ be different. Did you read what I said about child.cpp and follow the link? See my edit.

Answer (score 2):

Probably a typo but in base2.cpp it should say `Base2::Base2()` instead of `Base1::Base1()`

Answer (score 2):

You have defined `Base1::Base1()` in three .cpp files and have not defined `Base2::Base2()` at all.

You need to define each member function *exactly once*.

Answer (score 2):

You have not implemented

```
Base2::Base2();
```

But you've used it. That's why its undefined reference (link error)

In base2.cpp replace Base1::Base1() with Base2::Base2() and it will fix.

Use smarter more clear names to prevent these bugs.

Comment: you are right, I should use more clear names, I thought it would be ok for this little test...

Comment: what i suggest to my own students it to erase all the code and do it again with proper indentation, naming and etc. you have included some files inside IFDEF blocks and some outside it! it might cause duplicates.

Comment: @AbiusX: What? His use of #ifdef header guards is perfect. They _should not_ be found in the .cpp files. What do you see wrong with it? Also, your style of teaching prohibits students from learning basic debugging, which is quite a shame.

Comment: @Tomalak includes should be made inside the guard not outside it.

Comment: @AbiusX: It doesn't matter at all, because the headers that you're including have their own guards.

Comment: @Tomalak: first you dont know that for sure. You're not always using your own headers. Second even if this is true, you're forcing extra guard check to the precompiler. Either case its bad.

Comment: @AbiusX: (a) I can guarantee you that Qt uses header guards, and the OP's other headers are displayed in the question. (b) Putting #includes within your own header guards does not solve this "problem".

Comment: @Tomalak a) good practice b) wrong about it. think again. do an example for yourself.

Comment: @AbiusX: No, _you're_ wrong. Look: http://codepad.org/9SbrgdDe. I've used guards for base1.h and base2.h, and that still doesn't "fix" that I left them out on someLib.h.

Comment: @Tomalak: its not a problem to be fixed. its just extra work for the precompiler. please refer to the manual on how C precompiler works.

Comment: @AbiusX: I know how the precompiler works. I said that putting #includes within your own header guards doesn't solve the "problem" (quotes included), and you said that I was "wrong about it"; I have demonstrated that that is not true. Also, "extra work" resolving header guards inside rather than outside is completely negligible and certainly takes a back seat to legibility.

Comment: @Tomalak: my bad I thought you talked about performance problem. BTW its not negligible in many areas (such as network drives) and good practice in this case is mandatory.

Comment: @AbiusX: Any toolchain worth its salt can cache files read by the preprocessor. Good practice is absolutely _not_ "mandatory", but it's "good practice". :) For what it's worth, I code as you suggest (purely because there's no reason not to)... I just wouldn't go so far as to say that alternatives are "wrong". Certainly your claim that they'd lead to "duplicates" is ludicrous.

Comment: @Tomalak: I'm not gonna continue, since I told you it would cause unguarded files to duplicate, and you're saying Qt headers are not unguarded, which is totally irrelevant to my claim.

Comment: @AbiusX: Your students' loss.